# how do i map to a dictionary rather than a list?

Tags: python, xml, list, dictionary, lxml

i have the following function, which doe a basic job of mapping an lxml object to a dictionary...

```
from lxml import etree 

tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def xml_to_dict(el):
    d={}
    if el.text:
        print '***write tag as string'
        d[el.tag] = el.text
    else:
        d[el.tag] = {}
    children = el.getchildren()
    if children:
        d[el.tag] = map(xml_to_dict, children)
    return d

    v = xml_to_dict(root)
```

at the moment it gives me....

```
>>>print v
{'root': [{'a': '1'}, {'a': [{'b': '2'}, {'b': '2'}]}, {'aa': '1a'}]}
```

but i would like....

```
>>>print v
{'root': {'a': ['1', {'b': [2, 2]}], 'aa': '1a'}}
```

how do i rewrite the function xml_to_dict(el) so that i get the required output?

here's the xml i'm parsing, for clarity.

```
<root>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>
        <b>2</b>
        <b>2</b>
    </a>
    <aa>1a</aa>
</root>
```

thanks :)

Comment: Using a dictionary will only allow on element with key a or b how do you want that - ie best to show what your required output is

Comment: have rephrased question to include required output - thanks Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `map()` will always return a list, so the easy answer is "don't use `map()`". Instead, build a dictionary like you already are, by looping over `children` and assigning the result of `xml_to_dict(child)` to the dictionary key you want to use. It looks like you want to use the tag as the key and have the value be a list of items with that tag, so it would become something like:

```
import collections
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def xml_to_dict(el):
    d={}
    if el.text:
        print '***write tag as string'
        d[el.tag] = el.text
    child_dicts = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for child in el.getchildren():
        child_dicts[child.tag].append(xml_to_dict(child))
    if child_dicts:
        d[el.tag] = child_dicts
    return d

xml_to_dict(root)
```

This leaves the tag entry in the dict as a defaultdict; if you want a normal dict for some reason, use `d[el.tag] = dict(child_dicts)`. Note that, like before, if a tag has both text and children the text won't appear in the dict. You may want to think about a different layout for your dict to cope with that.

**EDIT:**

Code that would produce the output in your rephrased question wouldn't recurse in `xml_to_dict` -- because you only want a dict for the outer element, not for all child tags. So, you'd use something like:

```
import collections
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

def xml_to_item(el):
    if el.text:
        print '***write tag as string'
        item = el.text
    child_dicts = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for child in el.getchildren():
        child_dicts[child.tag].append(xml_to_item(child))
    return dict(child_dicts) or item

def xml_to_dict(el):
    return {el.tag: xml_to_item(el)}

print xml_to_dict(root)
```

This still doesn't handle tags with both text and children sanely, and it turns the `collections.defaultdict(list)` into a normal dict so the output is (almost) as you expect:

```
***write tag as string
***write tag as string
***write tag as string
***write tag as string
***write tag as string
***write tag as string
{'root': {'a': ['1', {'b': ['2', '2']}], 'aa': ['1a']}}
```

(If you really want integers instead of strings for the text data in the `b` tags, you'll have to explicitly turn them into integers somehow.)

Comment: sorry thomas, this is pretty much a correct answer to my original question but unfortunately i wasn't specific enough the first time. i've rephrased the question - hope you can help. sorry for the trouble...

Comment: thomas - sorry to bring this up again, but i'm having trouble implementing collections.OrderedDict rather than collections.defaultdict   -- hope you can help! thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

Simpler:

```
from lxml import etree    
def recursive_dict(element):
    return element.tag, dict(map(recursive_dict, element)) or element.text
```

To use it:

```
   >> tree = etree.parse(file_name)
   >> recursive_dict(tree.getroot())
   ('root', {'tag1': text, 'tag2': subtag21: {tag211: text}})
```

**Edit**: Output of question's example:

```
('root', {'a': {'b': '2'}, 'aa': '1a'})
```

It seems etree skips duplicate elements.