# How can a Markdown list be parsed to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, list, parsing, markdown

I have list such as the following:

```
- launchers
   - say hello
      - command: echo "hello" | festival --tts
      - icon: sayHello.png
   - say world
      - command: echo "world" | festival --tts
      - icon: sayWorld.png
   - wait
      - command: for ((x = 0; x < 10; ++x)); do :; done
      - icon: wait.png
```

I would like to parse it to a dictionary like the following:

```
{
    "launchers": {
        "say hello": {
            "command": "echo \"hello\" | festival --tts",
            "icon": "sayHello.png"
        }
        "say world": {
            "command": "echo \"world\" | festival --tts",
            "icon": "sayWorld.png"
        }
        "wait": {
            "command": "for ((x = 0; x < 10; ++x)); do :; done",
            "icon": "wait.png"
        }
    }
}
```

I've started on some very manual code that counts leading spaces (e.g. `len(line.rstrip()) - len(line.rstrip().lstrip())`), but I'm wondering if there is a more sensible way of approaching this. I am aware that JSON can be imported into Python, but this doesn't suit my purposes. So, how can a Markdown list in a file be parsed to a dictionary in Python? Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Here's some basic code I'm playing with now:

```
for line in open("configuration.md", 'r'):
    indentation = len(line.rstrip()) - len(line.rstrip().lstrip())
    listItem = line.split('-')[1].strip()
    listItemSplit = listItem.split(':')
    key = listItemSplit[0].strip()
    if len(listItemSplit) == 2:
        value = listItemSplit[1].strip()
    else:
        value = ""
    print(indentation, key, value)
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/reference.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112787/how-do-i-map-to-a-dictionary-rather-than-a-list).

Comment: That looks an awful lot like [YAML]( http://www.yaml.org) to me. Why not just use that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd assume a more rigid format and use a stack and a regular expression:

```
import re    

line = re.compile(r'( *)- ([^:\n]+)(?:: ([^\n]*))?\n?')
depth = 0
stack = [{}]
for indent, name, value in line.findall(inputtext):
    indent = len(indent)
    if indent > depth:
        assert not stack[-1], 'unexpected indent'
    elif indent < depth:
        stack.pop()
    stack[-1][name] = value or {}
    if not value:
        # new branch
        stack.append(stack[-1][name])
    depth = indent

result = stack[0]
```

This produces:

```
>>> import re
>>> inputtext = '''\
... - launchers
...    - say hello
...       - command: echo "hello" | festival --tts
...       - icon: sayHello.png
...    - say world
...       - command: echo "world" | festival --tts
...       - icon: sayWorld.png
...    - wait
...       - command: for ((x = 0; x < 10; ++x)); do :; done
...       - icon: wait.png
... '''
>>> line = re.compile(r'( *)- ([^:\n]+)(?:: ([^\n]*))?\n?')
>>> depth = 0
>>> stack = [{}]
>>> for indent, name, value in line.findall(inputtext):
...     indent = len(indent)
...     if indent > depth:
...         assert not stack[-1], 'unexpected indent'
...     elif indent < depth:
...         stack.pop()
...     stack[-1][name] = value or {}
...     if not value:
...         # new branch
...         stack.append(stack[-1][name])
...     depth = indent
... 
{'command': 'echo "hello" | festival --tts', 'icon': 'sayHello.png'}
{'command': 'echo "world" | festival --tts', 'icon': 'sayWorld.png'}
>>> result = stack[0]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(result)
{'launchers': {'say hello': {'command': 'echo "hello" | festival --tts',
                             'icon': 'sayHello.png'},
               'say world': {'command': 'echo "world" | festival --tts',
                             'icon': 'sayWorld.png'},
               'wait': {'command': 'for ((x = 0; x < 10; ++x)); do :; done',
                        'icon': 'wait.png'}}}
```

from your input text.

Comment: This is great ! But Wouldn't it be easier to parse the html ? [md to html](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/reference.html) and [html to dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112787/how-do-i-map-to-a-dictionary-rather-than-a-list).

Comment: @user3197452: somewhat overkill for this simple interpretation, I'd say.

Comment: @user3197452: note that there is no such thing as a definition list in markdown; there is no `- some term: term definition`, so you'd certainly still have to parse that out even from the HTML.

Comment: Well, put that in your Sylladex and Captchalogue it. That's excellent and concise. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered parsing the markdown, then sending the output to an HTML parser?

You could use the [Markdown package](https://pythonhosted.org/Markdown/) to parse the markdown to HTML.

Then you could use the built-in [HTMLParser library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html) to find the list and parse out the values. Alternatively you could use [lxml](http://lxml.de/) to parse the HTML.

This way you don't have to worry about the different possible levels of indentation. The markdown library takes care of that for you, and converts it to a format you can easily do additional processing to.

Comment: That's a clever idea. There would be the additional parsing necessary to extract the key-value pairs, but it's a good approach. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I used [a library](https://pypi.org/project/markdown-to-json/) that parses markdown to json, and then parsed the json as a Python dictionary:

```
import markdown_to_json
import json

my_markdown_json = markdown_to_json.jsonify(my_markdown_text)
my_dict = json.loads(my_markdown_json)
```